# Any Idea why PuLP is ignoring binary variables?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, pulp

When I solve the following code, the binaries for the `lines_selection` variable is not respected by PuLP. Can anyone please point me out to the reason why this could occur?

I've also attached the output LP file for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
plants = {1:('Plant 1'), 2: ('Plant 2')}
customers = {1: ('Customer 1'), 2: ('Customer 2'), 3: ('Customer 3')}
demands = {1: 50, 2: 50, 3: 25}
line_options = [1, 2]#{1:('Base'), 2: ('Double Base')}
line_options_cost = {1: 0, 2: 10}
line_options_capacity = {1: 50, 2: 100}
costs = {(1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1.5, (1,3): 1.5, (2,1): 1, (2,2): 1, (2,3): 1}

#Declare the problem
Investment_Decisions_Problem = LpProblem("Investment_Decisions", LpMinimize)

#Variable - Config of plant lines
lines_selection = LpVariable.dicts("Line Selection", [(i, j) for i in line_options for j in plants], cat='binary')
#lines_selection = LpVariable.dicts("Line Selection", [(i, j) for i in line_options for j in plants], lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat='interger')

#Variable - Flow of product from plant to customer
flow_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Flow", [(j, k) for j in plants for k in customers], lowBound = 0, cat = 'continuous')

#Adding an internal flow variable
internal_flow = LpVariable.dicts("Flow_Internal", [(j) for j in plants], lowBound = 0, cat = 'continuous')
#Setting objective
total_cost = lpSum(flow_vars[j,k] * costs[j,k] for j in plants for k in customers) + lpSum(lpSum(lines_selection[i,j] * line_options_cost[i] for i in line_options) for j in plants)

# Constraints
# C1 - All customer demand must be satisfied
for k in customers:                      
    Investment_Decisions_Problem += LpConstraint(e = lpSum([flow_vars[j,k] for j in plants]),
                                        sense = LpConstraintEQ,
                                        name = 'Demand_Satisfied_'+str(k),
                                        rhs = demands[k])

# C2 - Flow must be less than capacity
for j in plants:
    Investment_Decisions_Problem += LpConstraint(e = lpSum([flow_vars[j,k] for k in customers]) - internal_flow[j],
                                                 sense = LpConstraintEQ,
                                                 name = 'Equalizing_multi_echlon_flow_'+str(j),
                                                 rhs = 0)

# C3 - Balancing internal flow
for j in plants:
    Investment_Decisions_Problem += LpConstraint(e = lpSum([lines_selection[i,j] * line_options_capacity[i] for i in line_options]) - internal_flow[j],
                                                 sense = LpConstraintEQ,
                                                 name = 'Multi_Echelon_Flow_vs_capacity'+str(j),
                                                 rhs = 0)

# C4 - Only one line options is possible
for j in plants:
    Investment_Decisions_Problem += LpConstraint(e = lpSum([lines_selection[i,j] for i in line_options]),
                                                 sense = LpConstraintEQ,
                                                 name = 'Only one option'+str(j),
                                                 rhs = 1)
# Setting problem objective
Investment_Decisions_Problem.setObjective(total_cost)

# The problem data is written to an .lp file
Investment_Decisions_Problem.writeLP("Investment_Decisions_Flow.lp")
    
# The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
Investment_Decisions_Problem.solve()
```

Output LP file:

> 

* Investment_Decisions *
Minimize
OBJ: Flow_(1,*1) + 1.5 Flow*(1,*2) + 1.5 Flow*(1,*3) + Flow*(2,_1)

- Flow_(2,*2) + Flow*(2,*3) + 10 Line_Selection*(2,_1)
- 10 Line_Selection_(2,*2)
  Subject To
  Demand_Satisfied_1: Flow*(1,*1) + Flow*(2,*1) = 50
  Demand_Satisfied_2: Flow*(1,*2) + Flow*(2,*2) = 50
  Demand_Satisfied_3: Flow*(1,*3) + Flow*(2,*3) = 25
  Equalizing_multi_echlon_flow_1: Flow*(1,*1) + Flow*(1,*2) + Flow*(1,_3)

- Flow_Internal_1 = 0
  Equalizing_multi_echlon_flow_2: Flow_(2,*1) + Flow*(2,*2) + Flow*(2,_3)
- Flow_Internal_2 = 0
  Multi_Echelon_Flow_vs_capacity1: - Flow_Internal_1 + 50 Line_Selection_(1,_1)

- 100 Line_Selection_(2,*1) = 0
  Multi_Echelon_Flow_vs_capacity2: - Flow_Internal_2 + 50 Line_Selection*(1,_2)
- 100 Line_Selection_(2,*2) = 0
  Only_one_option1: Line_Selection*(1,*1) + Line_Selection*(2,*1) = 1
  Only_one_option2: Line_Selection*(1,*2) + Line_Selection*(2,*2) = 1
  Bounds
  0 <= Flow*(1,*1)
  0 <= Flow*(1,*2)
  0 <= Flow*(1,*3)
  0 <= Flow*(2,*1)
  0 <= Flow*(2,*2)
  0 <= Flow*(2,*3)
  0 <= Flow_Internal_1
  0 <= Flow_Internal_2
  Line_Selection*(1,*1) free
  Line_Selection*(1,*2) free
  Line_Selection*(2,*1) free
  Line_Selection*(2,_2) free
  End

> 

Clearly mentions that

> Line_Selection_(1,*1) free
> Line_Selection*(1,*2) free
> Line_Selection*(2,*1) free
> Line_Selection*(2,_2) free

are all free or unrestricted variables. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
TIA

Comment: In variable definition try making cat='Binary' and see. It may not recognize 'binary' and so treating it as continuous by default.

Answer (score 4):

You need to capitalize the first letter in the cat option:

```
# Variable - Config of plant lines
lines_selection = LpVariable.dicts("Line Selection", [(i, j) for i in line_options for j in plants], cat='Binary')
```

Comment: Sorry this does not solve it.

Comment: It should solve the issue of not recognizing "Line selection" as binary. For the general problem of your mathematical model see the answer of @A.Omidi and consider posing a new specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Some points should be considered.

- First, you defined the variable $FlowInternal_{j}$ as the slack variables on the constraints $C_2$ and $C_3$ but, forgot to limit it on the objective function. (For example, by a ***Big_M*** cost).
- Second, as this slack variable appears on the two different constraints, its values might be different which causes infeasibility.

One possible way would be by relaxing those constraints **from $=$ to $\leq$** to achieve what you want. Also, by solving the above problem based on the mentioned points, the solution and its corresponding LP file would be:

```
---- VAR objective      -INF  10125.000     +INF       .         

---- VAR x  

                       LOWER     LEVEL     UPPER   

Base       .plant_1      .        1.000     1.000       
Base       .plant_2      .        1.000     1.000       
double_Base.plant_1      .         .        1.000      
double_Base.plant_2      .         .        1.000      

---- VAR flow  

                      LOWER     LEVEL     UPPER    

plant_1.customer_1      .       50.000     +INF               
plant_1.customer_2      .         .        +INF           
plant_1.customer_3      .         .        +INF           
plant_2.customer_1      .         .        +INF           
plant_2.customer_2      .       50.000     +INF               
plant_2.customer_3      .       25.000     +INF              

---- VAR flow_internal  

           LOWER     LEVEL     UPPER    

plant_1      .       25.000     +INF                
plant_2      .       25.000     +INF
```

LP File:

```
objf..  objective - 10*x(double_Base,plant_1) - 10*x(double_Base,plant_2)
     
      - flow(plant_1,customer_1) - 1.5*flow(plant_1,customer_2)
     
      - 1.5*flow(plant_1,customer_3) - flow(plant_2,customer_1)
     
      - flow(plant_2,customer_2) - flow(plant_2,customer_3)
     
      - 200*flow_internal(plant_1) - 200*flow_internal(plant_2) =E= 0 ;

---- e1

e1(plant_1)..  x(Base,plant_1) + x(double_Base,plant_1) =E= 1 ;
e1(plant_2)..  x(Base,plant_2) + x(double_Base,plant_2) =E= 1 ;


---- e2 

e2(customer_1)..  flow(plant_1,customer_1) + flow(plant_2,customer_1) =E= 50 ;     
e2(customer_2)..  flow(plant_1,customer_2) + flow(plant_2,customer_2) =E= 50 ; 
e2(customer_3)..  flow(plant_1,customer_3) + flow(plant_2,customer_3) =E= 25 ;     


---- e3 

e3(plant_1)..  flow(plant_1,customer_1) + flow(plant_1,customer_2)
     
      + flow(plant_1,customer_3) - 3*flow_internal(plant_1) =L= 0 ; 
     
e3(plant_2)..  flow(plant_2,customer_1) + flow(plant_2,customer_2)
     
      + flow(plant_2,customer_3) - 3*flow_internal(plant_2) =L= 0 ; 
     

---- e4  =L=  

e4(plant_1)..  50*x(Base,plant_1) + 100*x(double_Base,plant_1)
     
      - 2*flow_internal(plant_1) =L= 0 ; 
     
e4(plant_2)..  50*x(Base,plant_2) + 100*x(double_Base,plant_2)
     
      - 2*flow_internal(plant_2) =L= 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing 'binary' to 'Binary' in the lines_selection definition gave me this in the LP file

```
\* Investment_Decisions *\
Minimize
OBJ: Flow_(1,_1) + 1.5 Flow_(1,_2) + 1.5 Flow_(1,_3) + Flow_(2,_1)
 + Flow_(2,_2) + Flow_(2,_3) + 10 Line_Selection_(2,_1)
 + 10 Line_Selection_(2,_2)
Subject To
Demand_Satisfied_1: Flow_(1,_1) + Flow_(2,_1) = 50
Demand_Satisfied_2: Flow_(1,_2) + Flow_(2,_2) = 50
Demand_Satisfied_3: Flow_(1,_3) + Flow_(2,_3) = 25
Equalizing_multi_echlon_flow_1: Flow_(1,_1) + Flow_(1,_2) + Flow_(1,_3)
 - Flow_Internal_1 = 0
Equalizing_multi_echlon_flow_2: Flow_(2,_1) + Flow_(2,_2) + Flow_(2,_3)
 - Flow_Internal_2 = 0
Multi_Echelon_Flow_vs_capacity1: - Flow_Internal_1 + 50 Line_Selection_(1,_1)
 + 100 Line_Selection_(2,_1) = 0
Multi_Echelon_Flow_vs_capacity2: - Flow_Internal_2 + 50 Line_Selection_(1,_2)
 + 100 Line_Selection_(2,_2) = 0
Only_one_option1: Line_Selection_(1,_1) + Line_Selection_(2,_1) = 1
Only_one_option2: Line_Selection_(1,_2) + Line_Selection_(2,_2) = 1
Bounds
 0 <= Flow_(1,_1)
 0 <= Flow_(1,_2)
 0 <= Flow_(1,_3)
 0 <= Flow_(2,_1)
 0 <= Flow_(2,_2)
 0 <= Flow_(2,_3)
 0 <= Flow_Internal_1
 0 <= Flow_Internal_2
Binaries
Line_Selection_(1,_1)
Line_Selection_(1,_2)
Line_Selection_(2,_1)
Line_Selection_(2,_2)
End
```